# How to capture SQL queries executed using Hibernate during a session and save them to a string array

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, junit

I get an empty array when try to get Sql queries using

```
Statistics statistics = sessionFactory.getStatistics(); 
String[] queries = statistics.getQueries();
```

Need to make a test that checks for the presence of "join" in SQL queries executed during a session.

```
@Test
    void testFetchProfile() {
        List<ItemsEntity> items = EntityHandler.getItemsEntities();     // ItemsEntity has one-to-many mapping
        List<PersonalAccountEntity> accounts = EntityHandler.getPersonalAccountEntities();  // has one-to-many mapping
        List<SellHistoryEntity> sellHistory = EntityHandler.getSellHistoryEntities();       // has many-to-one mapping
        @Cleanup SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateTestUtil.getSessionFactory();
        @Cleanup Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        persistEntitiesList(accounts, session);     // fills the db with entities of items
        persistEntitiesList(items, session);        // fills the db with entities of accounts
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            items.get(i).addPhoneOrder(sellHistory.get(i));
            accounts.get(i).addPurchase(sellHistory.get(i));
        }
        persistEntitiesList(sellHistory, session);  // fills the db with entities of sellHistory
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.clear();    // need to clean of 1st lvl cache to make join query
        session.enableFetchProfile("withPersonalAccount");  // FetchProfile has FetchMode.JOIN
        session.enableFetchProfile("withSellHistory");      // FetchProfile has FetchMode.JOIN
        Statistics statistics = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
        statistics.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        ItemsEntity itemsEntity = session.get(ItemsEntity.class, 1l);    
        itemsEntity.getPhoneOrders().get(0).getUser().getEmail();     // Here compiling required Sql query 
        session.getTransaction()
                .commit();
        String[] queries = statistics.getQueries();
        System.out.println("here: " + Arrays.toString(queries));
        boolean checkForJoin = Arrays.stream(queries)
                .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("join"));
        assertThat(checkForJoin).isTrue();
    }
```

As a result, I get the following code:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ie1_0.item_id,
        ie1_0.brand,
        ie1_0.color,
        ie1_0.currency,
        ie1_0.internal_memory,
        ie1_0.model,
        ie1_0.os,
        ie1_0.price,
        ie1_0.quantity,
        ie1_0.ram,
        po1_0.item_id,
        po1_0.sell_id,
        po1_0.quantity,
        po1_0.sell_date,
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.type,
        u1_0.address,
        u1_0.birthday,
        u1_0.city,
        u1_0.country_enum,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.gender_enum,
        u1_0.image,
        u1_0.name,
        pgp_sym_decrypt(u1_0.password::bytea, current_setting('encrypt.key')),
        u1_0.phone_number,
        u1_0.surname,
        u1_0.discount_enum 
    from
        market.items ie1_0 
    left join
        market.sell_history po1_0 
            on ie1_0.item_id=po1_0.item_id 
    left join
        market.personal_account u1_0 
            on u1_0.id=po1_0.user_id 
    where
        ie1_0.item_id=?
here: []    <--- "System.out.println("here: " + Arrays.toString(queries));"
```

As you can see we get an empty array.
[In debug also we can see empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F20Yy.png)

The configuration file contains the required property line to enable statistics:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
--->    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="entity.PersonalAccountEntity"/>
        <mapping class="entity.SellHistoryEntity"/>
        <mapping class="entity.ItemsEntity"/>
        <mapping class="entity.ProfileInfoEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried explicitly specifying the value to enable statistics directly in the code

```
 statistics.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

in HibernateTestUtil:

```
Configuration configuration = HibernateSessionFactory.buildConfiguration();
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
        configuration.configure();
```